# matching 8 digit of alphanumeric in a string

Tags: php, regex, php-5.3

I wanted to use regular expression to check if a string has a word that contains 8 digit of alphanumeric character, ignoring uppercase and lowercase (meaning that 2HJS1289 and 2hjs1289 should match). I know I can use preg to do this, and so far I have this:

```
preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]/i', $string)
```

I am unsure however on how to limit it only to 8 digits/character scheme.

Comment: `preg_match( '/[A-Za-z0-9]{8}/', $string )` for an 8 character alphanum string.  You can change `{8}` to `{4,8}` if  you want to match anywhere from 4 to 8 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
preg_match('/\b([A-Z0-9]{8})\b/i', $string)
```

The {8} matches exactly 8 times. I added the capturing group (the parentheses), in case you needed to extract the actual match.

You can also use {min,max} to match the pattern repeating between min and max times (inclusive, I think). Or you can leave one of the parameters out to leave it open ended. Eg {min,} to match at least min times

Comment: This will match, for example, a 9 char word. For exactly 8, word boundaries are required.

Comment: @pguardiario: Word boundaries are a bad idea since a string like `abc456gh_` will not match. The only way to match exactly 8 alphanumeric characters seems to be using lookarounds: `(?<![A-Za-z0-9])` and `(?![A-Za-z0-9])`

Comment: No, that string shouldn't match anyway.

Comment: @pguardiario: test it.

Comment: Without word boundaries or anchors, this regex will match any input string that CONTAINS an 8-character alphanumeric string.

Comment: @casimir - test what, your expectations?

Comment: Good suggestion on the word boundaries, thanks pguardiario. I've added that in, and upvoted your answer for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

For exactly 8 char word you will need to use word boundaries: `\b`

```
preg_match('/\b[A-Z\d]{8}\b/i', $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

[a-zA-Z0-9] - will match upper or lowercase letters or numbers

{8} - will specify to match 8 of the preceeding token

put it together:

```
 preg_match('/([A-Za-z0-9]{8})/i', $string)
```

[example](http://regexr.com?36ar8)

Comment: You don't need the trailing "i" since you're using `[a-zA-z]`.